# Copy file to ansible host with custom variables substituted

Tags: copy, ansible

I'm working on an ansible-playbook which should help to generate build agents for a continuous delivery pipeline. Among other issues, I'll need to install an oracle client on such an agent. I want to do something like

```
- name: "Provide response file"
  copy: src=/custom.rsp dest=/opt/oracle
```

Within the custom.rsp file I've got some variables to be substituted. Normally, one could do it with a separate shell command like this:

```
- name: "Substitute Vars"
  shell: "sed 's|<PARAMETER>|<VALUE>|g' -i /opt/oracle/custom.rsp"
```

I don't like it, though. There should be a more convinient way to do this. Anybody giving me a hint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to be using a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) rather than copying a static file.

Also, when using the copy or template modules, the `dest` parameter is a full path AND filename, not just a path.  So if you want to end up with a copy of `custom.rsp` in the directory /opt/oracle then you need to do this:

```
- name: "Provide response file"
  template: src=/custom.rsp dest=/opt/oracle/custom.rsp
```

Comment: Perfect match! But you should fix the `copy` to be a `template` in your answer. Thx, this works. I'll only need to template the variables by f.e. {{ ansible_hostname }} in the template and thats it. Great solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to extend Bruce's answer with an example:
This is part of my inventory.yaml:

```
kafka_stage:
  children:
    kafka_with_zookeeper_stage:
    kafka_only_stage:
  vars:
    zookeeper_hosts: "kafka-stage01:2181,kafka-stage02:2181,kafka-stage03:2181"
kafka_with_zookeeper_stage:
  hosts:
    kafka-stage01:
      broker_id: 0
    kafka-stage02:
      broker_id: 1
  vars:
    services:
      kafka:
      zookeeper:
```

This is part of a configuration file:

```
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id={{ broker_id }}
# {{ zookeeper_hosts }}
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{{ ansible_host }}:9092
# {{ services }}
```

This command in a playbook:

```
- name: Copy to Host
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: my_configfile.properties
    dest: /tmp/hejsan.properties
```

Gave me this on the remote host kafka-stage02:

```
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1
# kafka-stage01:2181,kafka-stage02:2181,kafka-stage03:2181
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka-stage02:9092
# {'kafka': None, 'zookeeper': None}
```